# X Theme Custom Header Not Calling out

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom page template built in a child theme and I need to call out a custom header.

I have template-home.php page template calling out

```
<?php get_header('home'); ?>
```

for the header.

I have a saved `wp-header-home.php` with a little custom button that I need to get.

The page template is unsuccessful at calling out the custom header-home, rather it's calling out the default `wp-header.php`.  I can see when I add my changes into that file, they're reflected.

So, what's going on?  Why does my

```
<?php get_header('home'); ?>
```

not work to get the `wp-header-home.php`?  What am I doing wrong?

This is the site in question: http://va.northwaydesigns.com

Comment: http://va.northwaydesigns.com/ this is the site in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the file with header-home.php